# How UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication validates the JWT token (with local mode)

Tags: jwt, identityserver3

I have the following code in my application, say WebApp1:

```
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {

            Authority = "IdentityServerPath",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "write", "role", "all_claims" },
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local,
        });
```

Caller/Client application passes the JWT token to WebApp1. How does the WebApp1 knows that the JWT token is valid? Does WebApp1 needs to know the public key of the JWT token? if not how the signature of JWT can be verified by WebApp1? Please note that I am using ValidationMode as local, so WebApp1 will not contact IdentityServer to validate the JWT token.

Comment: Hello, is your client using implicit flow?

Answer (score 6):

For the option of "local", `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` uses the discovery document (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) to dynamically download the signing materials needed to validate JWTs.

The other option of "validation endpoint" uses either the custom token validation endpoint (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/accessTokenValidation.html), or if a client id and secret is configured, then the standard OAuth2 Introspection (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) endpoint is used to validate the token (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/introspection.html).

The last option of "both" will dynamically determine which of the two approaches described above based upon some heuristics on the incoming access token presented to the Web API.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I need to do validation explicitly. I just learnt that validation is already happening as part of: UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication  code itself.